# Creating Table using Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an dynamic table using Javascript and jQuery but the result is messed up. Can you tell me whats wrong with my code?

Down below you can find my code as well as an example on JSFiddle.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/crgco8dL/) is the code so you can try it out yourself.

```js
var students = [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "friends": ["Tim", "Ann", "Lou", "Thomas", "Elias"]
}, {
  "name": "Harry Potter",
  "friends": ["Ron", "Hermione"]
}, {
  "name": "James May",
  "friends": ["Hammnond", "Richard"]
}];



for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var student = students[i];
  $('#table').append('<tr><td rowspan="' + student.friends.length + '">' + student.name + '</td>');

  for (var u = 0; u < student.friends.length; u++) {
    if (u == 0) {
      $('#table').append('<td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>');
    } else {
      $('#table').append('<tr><td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h2>
Current Result
</h2>
  <table id="table" border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <hr>
  <h2>
  Perfect Result
  </h2>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">John Doe</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ann</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lou</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thomas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elias</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Harry Potter</td>
      <td>Ron</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">James May</td>
      <td>Hammond</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Richard</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This might solve your problem,  Check this working fiddle
>   https://jsfiddle.net/scgqwLp5/

**JS**

```
var students = [{
"name": "John Doe",
"friends": ["Tim", "Ann", "Lou", "Thomas", "Elias"]
}, {
"name": "Harry Potter",
"friends": ["Ron", "Hermione"]
}, {
"name": "James May",
"friends": ["Hammnond", "Richard"]
}];



for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
var student = students[i];
$('#table').append('<tr><td rowspan="' + (student.friends.length + 1) + '">' + student.name + '</td>');

for (var u = 0; u < student.friends.length; u++) {
$('#table').append('<tr><td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>');
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<h2>
Current Result
</h2>
<table id="table" border=1>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Friends</th>
</tr>
</table>

<hr>
<h2>
Perfect Result
</h2>
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Friends</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="5">John Doe</td>
  <td>Tim</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Ann</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lou</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Thomas</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Elias</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Harry Potter</td>
  <td>Ron</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hermione</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">James May</td>
  <td>Hammond</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Richard</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/crgco8dL/1/)

```
<body>
<h2>
Current Result
</h2>
  <table id="table" border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <hr>
  <h2>
  Perfect Result
  </h2>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">John Doe</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ann</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lou</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thomas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elias</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Harry Potter</td>
      <td>Ron</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">James May</td>
      <td>Hammond</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Richard</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

var students = [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "friends": ["Tim", "Ann", "Lou", "Thomas", "Elias"]
}, {
  "name": "Harry Potter",
  "friends": ["Ron", "Hermione"]
}, {
  "name": "James May",
  "friends": ["Hammnond", "Richard"]
}];



for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var student = students[i];
  var str = "";
 str +='<tr><td rowspan="' + student.friends.length + '">' +   student.name + '</td>';

  for (var u = 0; u < student.friends.length; u++) {
    if (u == 0) {
      str += '<td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>';
    } else {
      str += '<tr><td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>';
    }
  }
   $('#table').append(str);
}
```

It will work for you. i changed in your code itself.
i user str rather appending again and again.

Comment: I like the idea of using a string instead of adding all the code directly to the table. Worked out fine for me after fixing a few minor problems (closing `<tr>` tags)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var students = [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "friends": ["Tim", "Ann", "Lou", "Thomas", "Elias"]
}, {
  "name": "Harry Potter",
  "friends": ["Ron", "Hermione"]
}, {
  "name": "James May",
  "friends": ["Hammnond", "Richard"]
}];



for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
  var student = students[i];
 var str = '<tr><td rowspan="' + student.friends.length + '">' + student.name + '</td>';
  for (var u = 0; u < student.friends.length; u++) {
    if (u == 0) {
      str += '<td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>';
    } else {
      str += '<tr><td>' + student.friends[u] + '</td></tr>';
    }
 if(u == student.friends.length - 1){
  $('#table').append(str);
 }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h2>
Current Result
</h2>
  <table id="table" border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <hr>
  <h2>
  Perfect Result
  </h2>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Friends</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">John Doe</td>
      <td>Tim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ann</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lou</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thomas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Elias</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Harry Potter</td>
      <td>Ron</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">James May</td>
      <td>Hammond</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Richard</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```